# Enable/disable post revisions programmatically

Tags: php

Is there a way to temporarily disable revisions.... I have noticed that `wp_update_post` is very slow and creates revisions I don't need.
The fix could be to disable revisions before issuing `wp_update_post` and re-enable the feature once done....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep posts updated, I am working with WordPress 4.4 and to enable/disable post revisions programmatically use:

```
remove_action( 'post_updated', 'wp_save_post_revision' );
$post_id = wp_update_post( $arg );
add_action( 'post_updated', 'wp_save_post_revision' );
```

Comment: This answer was correct at the time it was authored, but there was a bug in WordPress which has been fixed quite some time ago [see trac ticket #16215](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16215). This fix rendered this answer wrong. @Riccardo posted a [corrected answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3398/63847) by now, which should be the accepted answer as of now.

Answer (score 6):

Seems this will do the job:

```
remove_action('pre_post_update', 'wp_save_post_revision');// stop revisions
```

and

```
add_action('pre_post_update', 'wp_save_post_revision');//  enable revisions again
```

Comment: How/where are you using this?  I've got a plugin file with a custom function that that calls the `remove_action` -- but I can't figure out what hook to attach my function to.  I've tried add_action on `save_post` & `pre_post_update` and a hundred others. Nothing seems to have an effect. (The function is running, but revisions are still created.)  The only place I can get the revisions to not be created is with apply_filter on `wp_insert_post_data` which doesn't create the revision, but also doesn't save the modified post data at all either.  @JHoffmann @Riccardo

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to set `WP_POST_REVISIONS` contant to `false`, additional information about post [revision management](http://codex.wordpress.org/Revision_Management)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wp_revisions_to_keep` filter and `return 0` to effectively disable revisions, specify a maximum number of revisions to keep, or `return -1` for the default of unlimited revisions. You can add the post parameter to the filter if you would like to adjust for post type.

```php
function my_disable_revisions( $num ) { 
    return 0; 
}
add_filter( 'wp_revisions_to_keep', 'my_disable_revisions' );
```