# Disable revision access for a specific user role

Tags: revisions

I want to disable revision access for a specific user role.

I saw the code posted here: [Enable/disable post revisions programmatically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/enable-disable-post-revisions-programmatically)  but am worried that even with a clause to check the current admin users role that this code would disable the revision access site wide, not just to that specific user in that specific moment.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this in the end by removing access to the revisions meta box for certain user types...

```
if (get_current_user_role()=="custom_user_role"){
function my_remove_revisions() {
    remove_meta_box('revisionsdiv', 'apartments', 'normal');
}
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_revisions' );
}
```